# Uninstalled Snap by mistake

Tags: snap, 20.04

By mistake I removed snapd from my ubuntu 20.04 I ran this command

```
sudo dpkg -r snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

Now, as a result, some of my apps are not opening. How can I reverse this change?

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y && sudo apt-get install snapd
```

The result was

> Package snapd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is
>   only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'snapd' has no installation candidate

Comment: Welcome! The package name is `snap`, not `snapd`.

Answer (score 1):

You should type `snap`, **not** `snapd`.

```
sudo apt-get install snap
```